# A metric space in $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ is compact iff closed and bounded

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

$\mathbb{R^{2}}$ is a metric space with distance function $d((x_{1},y_{1}),(x_{2},y_{2})) = \sqrt{(x_{1}-x_{2})^{2} + (y_{1}-y_{2})^{2}}$. Want to show that a subset of $\mathbb{R^{2}}$ is compact iff closed and bounded.

To be honest, I didn't get the whole metric space at all and been working on this for over 5-6 hours with no clue what I'm going to do. I know Heine-Borel theorem for $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm clueless about whole metric space stuff. Like how can I write an open cover for this subset or any metric space($\mathbb{R^{2}}$ or $\mathbb{R^{}}$ doesn't matter) at all? I know that the open ball definition etc but completely lost.

Comment: There is a typo in the defined metric. ⇒ is true for all metric space but ⇐ is not true in general and the proof of ⇐ will be highly similar to the proof on the real line…just take a decreasing sequence of rectangles instead of intervals in this case. So did you study the proof of that on the real line?

Comment: Yes I did, also thanks for the hints.

Comment: If it is not bounded then it is easily seen not to be compact (consider the cover of open disks with radius $n=1,2,3...$). If not close a similar argument works. So, compact implies closed and bounded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the subset is bounded it can be enclosed in a closed square.
By Heine Borel the edges are compact. Thus the subset is included
in a compact square for the square is the product of compact spaces,
hence compact.  Finally, since the subset is a closed subset of a
compact space, it is compact.

Simularily, a closed and bounded subset of R^d is compact.
Metric spaces whose closed and bounded subsets are compact
are called Borel compact spaces.  A closed subspace of a
Borel compact space is Borel compact.  The plain with an open
disk removed, for example.